# Creating publishing page in in SharePoint timer job throws MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, timer-jobs

I'm doing a simple news importer for a sharepoint site using timer job that runs every few minutes. The code below runs fine if I run it in a web part but throws MissingMethodException when ran in timer job's Execute method.

The full exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled by user code
  Message="No parameterless constructor defined for this object."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartSerializer.get_DefaultControl()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.Serialize(PersonalizationScope scope)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.get_Links()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddWebPartToStore(WebPart webPart, Int32 viewId, String viewGuid)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddWebPartInternal(SPSupersetWebPart superset, Boolean throwIfLocked)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.AddWebPartInternal(WebPart webPart, String zoneId, Int32 zoneIndex, Boolean throwIfLocked)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.AddWebPart(WebPart webPart, String zoneId, Int32 zoneIndex)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPage.CopyAllWebParts(String destinationPageUrlServerRelative, SPWeb destinationPageWeb, String sourcePageUrlServerRelative, SPWeb sourcePageWeb, Boolean shouldOverwriteDestinationWebParts)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPageCollection.<>c__DisplayClass5.<Add>b__0()
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.FirstChanceHandler.ExceptionFilter(Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, FilterBlock filter, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.ULS.SendWatsonOnExceptionTag(ULSTagID tagID, ULSCat categoryID, String output, Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingPageCollection.Add(String name, PageLayout layout)
       at Virtua.SharePoint.Mercator.NewsImportJob.Execute(Guid contentDbId)
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvoke.Invoke(TimerJobExecuteData& data, Int32& result)
  InnerException:
```

The code:

```
var SPWebUri = new Uri("http://.../News/");
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPWebUri.AbsoluteUri))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPWebUri.AbsolutePath)) // tried 0x29A's anwser, but it didn't work
    // using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
        SPContentTypeId contentTypeId = new SPContentTypeId("...");

        PageLayout layout = publishingWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts(contentTypeId).First(l => l.Name == "....aspx");
        PublishingPageCollection pages = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages();

        var spFilename = "testing";

        // error line below
        var newPage = pages.Add(String.Format("{0}.aspx", spFilename), layout);

        // set newPage's fields

        // check-in and publish page
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a faulty web part on my page layout. I was using `SPContext.Current...` in constructor. Now, apparently, `SPContext` stuff just isn't there when executing timer job code (not so surprising either).

Since the error was not handled, web part manager tried to replace my part with an `ErrorWebPart` (the one normally telling the user something went wrong). For some reason this works fine when displaying page in browser. But in timer job, SharePoint tries to create `ErrorWebPart` through reflection using *parameterless constructor* which is *not defined* in `ErrorWebPart` and the whole thing just collapses with `MissingMethodException`.

Moving the offending code to `CreateChildControls` method (where I have error handling) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but could it be that you need to provide the url parameter for site.OpenWeb() If url parameter is empty, the top-level site must be opened. Which may explain why it works in a web part but not from the timer job. See [MSDN - Site.OpenWeb Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.site.openweb.aspx) for details.

Regards

Comment: No, that didn't work. +1 for pointing out another possible bug :-)